# How to create array from certain elements in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, rows, python-2.x

I have an array with 7 columns, 52 rows. I want to create an array of just the 4th column but only based a 1 or 0 value from the 7th column. Can someone help?

```
for row in dataArray:
    if (row[6] == 1):
        sumNSal += int(row[4])
    if (row[6] == 0):
        sumNSalR += int(row[4])
print sumNSal, sumNSalR
```

My desire is to actually add up some numbers in the 4th column, but only add numbers that correspond to a 0 in the last column. My dataArray is as such: the last column consists of 0's and 1's. Hope this clears up confusion.

```
['244', '128', '385', '23521', '5230', '5334', '0']
['59', '155', '203', '9160', '2459', '493', '1']
['120', '281', '392', '21900', '6304', '6115', '0']
['120', '291', '419', '22354', '6590', '6346', '0']
['120', '238', '363', '17421', '5362', '6225', '0']
['65', '180', '234', '10531', '3622', '449', '1']
['120', '306', '372', '22147', '4406', '4998', '1']
['90', '214', '305', '14025', '4173', '966', '1']
['96', '155', '169', '8812', '1955', '1260', '0']
['120', '133', '188', '11729', '3224', '6442', '1']
['62', '148', '192', '8896', '2409', '1236', '0']
['120', '274', '426', '20987', '2066', '3360', '1']
['116', '154', '321', '17655', '5946', '4231', '0']
['59', '120', '164', '7085', '1925', '1280', '1']
['80', '261', '284', '13089', '4166', '1123', '1']
['120', '338', '375', '21453', '5257', '5206', '1']
['80', '77', '133', '7790', '1988', '4443', '1']
['100', '204', '318', '18309', '4156', '4585', '1']
['60', '97', '213', '8872', '1914', '1675', '1']
['110', '178', '280', '17881', '5173', '5686', '1']
['120', '232', '336', '17004', '4630', '907', '0']
['135', '316', '442', '23829', '7489', '3351', '0']
['59', '163', '191', '9424', '2051', '1756', '1']
['60', '96', '202', '12474', '3803', '2123', '0']
['25', '74', '83', '4078', '2008', '4531', '1']
['221', '514', '776', '36029', '1288', '2543', '1']
['64', '91', '214', '8782', '4729', '4446', '1']
['62', '146', '204', '8951', '2367', '1064', '0']
['108', '255', '366', '17446', '5933', '2987', '1']
['62', '144', '220', '6164', '2782', '411', '1']
['90', '151', '286', '2853', '4651', '4197', '0']
['146', '100', '375', '21334', '6857', '1198', '0']
['62', '174', '189', '8082', '2143', '1209', '1']
['30', '54', '88', '3948', '3025', '137', '1']
['79', '213', '278', '11649', '2905', '1279', '0']
['44', '127', '158', '7850', '1498', '1273', '1']
['120', '208', '423', '29035', '6236', '3524', '0']
['100', '255', '300', '17532', '3547', '2561', '1']
['49', '110', '177', '8197', '2810', '3874', '1']
['123', '208', '336', '22555', '6059', '6402', '1']
['82', '114', '136', '8459', '1995', '1911', '1']
['58', '166', '205', '10412', '2245', '1122', '1']
['110', '228', '323', '16661', '4029', '3893', '1']
['62', '183', '222', '12406', '2784', '2212', '1']
['86', '62', '200', '11312', '3720', '2959', '1']
['102', '326', '355', '14499', '3866', '3006', '1']
['135', '157', '471', '24274', '7485', '1344', '0']
['78', '154', '203', '9327', '3672', '1242', '1']
['83', '224', '390', '12362', '3995', '1484', '1']
['60', '48', '213', '10644', '2820', '1154', '0']
['54', '119', '144', '7556', '2088', '245', '1']
['120', '217', '327', '20182', '4432', '6274', '0']
```

Comment: "ut only based a 1 or 0 value from the 7th column." Wut?

Comment: You need to explain more about your problem. Share your current list and the desired output, and also share what you tried.

Comment: cpython arrays, numpy arrays, vanilla lists?
Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: So you've posted your dataArray, now please show us an example of what it should look like after the transformation.

Comment: I am a bit more confused now. Is `sumNSal` and `sumNSalR` integer variables or a list because you haven't initialized them. Also, the 7th column in your data contains a string `1` or `0` rather than numeric ones. But the code you have written is based on numberic values.

Comment: It should be an array of just numbers from the 4 column.

Comment: They're initialized on the top of the script.

Comment: @Philip In your code, `if(row[6] == 1)`, shouldn't it be `if(row[6] == '1')`? Because the list contains string values.

Comment: I tried that as well, still no results

Comment: From your code it looks like you're trying to keep **two** different sums, `sumNSal` and `sumNSalR`, not one as you state. Also, while `row[6]` is the seventh column, `row[4]` is not the fourth.

Comment: I'll recreate the question to include my full code and better examples. I apologize for the inconsistencies and confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your 2D list is `A`, then

```
# 0-based indexing
# assuming you want to take 4th column only when 7th column is `0`.
# assuming 7th column contains either '1' or '0'
X = [int(row[3]) for row in A if row[6] == '0']
```

`X` will be a list such that for each row in your 2D list, only those 4th column values will be included if the corresponding value in 7th column is `'0'`.

This syntax is called List Comprehension and you can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: I really wanted this to work, but it just returns a [ [ ] ]

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want boolean indexing. I'm assuming we're talking about numpy. Note that if you want the values corresponding to zeros in your last column, you just need to negate the boolean logic with `~`.

```
import numpy as np

# data array
A = np.random.random([52,7])

# Make a boolean from your seventh column
tf = np.array(A[:,6], dtype=bool)

# select values from the fourth column
a = A[~tf, 3]

# sum them
a.sum()

# This can be combined into one line if desired. Something like:
thesum = A[A[:,6] == 0, 3].sum()
```

Comment: There's no mention of `numpy` anywhere in the question. Paraphrasing a well-known adage: When the only tool you know how to use is a hammer, all problems start looking like nails...

Comment: I provided a clear answer to the question as originally asked, while making some reasonable assumptions because the question wasn't very clear. Sometimes a nail is a nail.

Comment: Total overkill for such a simple problem IMO. Perhaps you should first ask the OP in a comment before making such an assumption.